# Can I use '1 spot - cs6 pure isolated power' to connect these pedals on PedalTrain Nano?

Tags: guitar, effects-pedal, setup

Can I use '1 spot - cs6 pure isolated power' to connect these pedals on PedalTrain Nano?

- CryBaby Mini Wah CMB-95
- Ibanez TubeScreamer TS9DX 9
- Friedman Dirty Shirley
- Mooer Audio Mod Factory MKII
- Flashback Mini Delay

Comment: I thought a Dirty Shirley was an amp, not a pedal? Can you edit this to add some kind of separator between each pedal? Some are obvious but they’re kind of run together and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

There are four considerations when using power packs.

1. AC or DC? Most, except Alesis Nano stuff to my knowledge, use DC.
2. Voltage? Most will use 9v, some 12v, occasionally 15v.
3. If DC, then polarity? Using  the ubiquitous DC plug, there's a 50:50 chance of centre pin being positive - or negative. Wrong one just won't work.
4. Is there enough ampage (current - more usually milliampage) in the power supply to provide for all the pedals needing power?

There is a remote 5th - size of DC plug, but that's rare that the usual one won't fit. Even AC to DC. Beware!

Check on those four criteria, and you can work it all out fairly easily.